# I'm building a Minesweeper.When I press the middle menu item, I want the screen to resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm building a Minesweeper. I'm new to this. When I press the middle menu item, I want the screen to resize. But when I press the medium item, there is no change.

```
package mayintarlasi;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class MayınTarlası extends JFrame {

    private final JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private final JMenu menuAyarlar = new JMenu();
    private final JMenu menuYardım = new JMenu();
    private final JMenu menuYeniOyun = new JMenu();
    private final JMenuItem menuItemEasy = new JMenuItem();
    private final JMenuItem menuItemMedium = new JMenuItem();
    private final JMenuItem menuItemHard = new JMenuItem();
    OyunAlani oyunAlani = new OyunAlani();

    public MayınTarlası() {

        ekranTasarla();

    }

    public void ekranTasarla() {

        //menubar işlemleri
        add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //menu işlemleri
        menuAyarlar.setText("Ayarlar");
        menuYardım.setText("Yardim");
        menubar.add(menuAyarlar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        menubar.add(menuYardım);

        //menuYeniOyun işlemleri
        menuAyarlar.add(menuYeniOyun);
        menuYeniOyun.setText("Yeni oyun");

        //menuItemKolay işlemleri
        menuYeniOyun.add(menuItemEasy);
        menuItemEasy.setText("Kolay");

        //menuItemOrta işlemleri
        menuYeniOyun.add(menuItemMedium);
        menuItemMedium.setText("Orta");

        //menuItemZor işlemleri
        menuYeniOyun.add(menuItemHard);
        menuItemHard.setText("Zor");


        add(new OyunAlani(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();

        menuItemEasy.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            System.out.println("BURAK");
            oyunAlani.boyutAl(10);

        });
        menuItemMedium.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            System.out.println("BURAK");
            oyunAlani.boyutAl(20);
        });
        menuItemHard.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            System.out.println("BURAK");
            oyunAlani.boyutAl(20);
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
package mayintarlasi;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OyunAlani extends JPanel {

    private static int gelen = 15;
    private  int boslukBoyutu = 15;
    private  int[][] boslukKolay = new int[20][20];
    private  int[][] boslukOrta = new int[20][20];
    private  int[][] boslukZor = new int[20][20];
    private JLabel[][] labelDizisi = new JLabel[gelen][gelen];
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(gelen * boslukBoyutu, gelen * boslukBoyutu);

    Image img = new ImageIcon(OyunAlani.class.getResource("/resources/kutu.png")).getImage();

    public void boyutBelirle() {
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
    }

    public OyunAlani() {
        setLayout(null);
        yerleştirJLabel();
        boyutBelirle();
    }

    public void yerleştirJLabel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gelen; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gelen; j++) {
                labelDizisi[i][j] = new JLabel();
                labelDizisi[i][j].setBounds(15 * i, 15 * j, 15, 15);
                labelDizisi[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                add(labelDizisi[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void boyutAl(int gelen) {
        OyunAlani.gelen = gelen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [ask].

Comment: Please tell the details of your code and your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create:

```
OyunAlani oyunAlani = new OyunAlani();
```

But then you add a DIFFERENT instance to the frame:

```
add(new OyunAlani(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The code should be:

```
//add(new OyunAlani(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(oyunAlani, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Edit:

```
public void boyutAl(int gelen) {
    OyunAlani.gelen = gelen;
}
```

So what do you expect that code to do?

If you want it to change the number of components, then you need to recreate all your components.

So I would guess you need to:

1. remove all the comoponents from the panel
2. invoke your `yerleştirJLabel()` to recreate all the components using the new size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work

Comment: @Burak see edit.